# Resolve a Clojure string to a Java static member

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

In the past I've been able to, e.g.

```
==> ((resolve (symbol "first")) [1 2 3])
1
```

but it doesn't seem to work in the same way for a Java static member. Like for instance I have an `enum` like this in its own file:

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;

public enum RelTypes implements RelationshipType {
  KNOWS
}
```

and in my Clojure code (using neo4j) I want to:

```
(defn relate-to
  [from to reltype-as-keyword]
  (.createRelationshipTo from to 
    (resolve (symbol (str "RelTypes/" (.toUpperCase (name reltype-as-keyword)))))))
```

but `(resolve (symbol (str "RelTypes/" (.toUpperCase (name reltype-as-keyword)))))` returns nil.

**Update:**

I see from [another library](https://github.com/wagjo/borneo/blob/master/src/borneo/core.clj#L107) that `reify` could be used (i.e., *not* using the enum defined elsewhere, instead creating `RelationshipType`s on the fly).

e.g.

```
(reify RelationshipType
  (^String name [this] "KNOWS"))
```

But how do you do it by using the enum defined in the java file outside of the Clojure code?

Answer (score 1):

For this enum

```
package hello;

public enum MyEnum {

    ONE, TWO;

}
```

the following snippet of Clojure works:

```
(Enum/valueOf hello.MyEnum "ONE")
```